# How to define a function whose output type depends on the input type

Tags: scala, types, shapeless

Given the following classes:

```
case class AddRequest(x: Int, y: Int)
case class AddResponse(sum: Int)
case class ToUppercaseRequest(str: String)
case class ToUppercaseResponse(upper: String)
```

How do I define in a typesafe manner some function:

```
def process(req: ???): ???
```

Such that the following should hold true:

```
val r1: AddResponse = process(AddRequest(2, 3))
val r2: ToUppercaseResponse = process(ToUppercaseRequest("aaa"))
```

Also, the following should *not* compile:

```
val r3 = process("somestring")
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is both entirely possible and a totally reasonable thing to do in Scala. This kind of thing is all over Shapeless, for example, and something similar (but less principled) is the basis of the magnet pattern that shows up in Spray, etc.

Update: note that the following solution assumes that "given the following classes" means you don't want to touch the case classes themselves. If you don't care, see the second part of the answer below.

You'd want a type class that maps input types to output types:

```
case class AddRequest(x: Int, y: Int)
case class AddResponse(sum: Int)
case class ToUppercaseRequest(str: String)
case class ToUppercaseResponse(upper: String)

trait Processable[In] {
  type Out
  def apply(in: In): Out
}
```

And then some type class instances:

```
object Processable {
  type Aux[I, O] = Processable[I] { type Out = O }

  implicit val toUppercase: Aux[ToUppercaseRequest, ToUppercaseResponse] =
    new Processable[ToUppercaseRequest] {
      type Out = ToUppercaseResponse
      def apply(in: ToUppercaseRequest): ToUppercaseResponse =
        ToUppercaseResponse(in.str.toUpperCase)
    }

  implicit val add: Aux[AddRequest, AddResponse] =
    new Processable[AddRequest] {
      type Out = AddResponse
      def apply(in: AddRequest): AddResponse = AddResponse(in.x + in.y)
    }
}
```

And now you can define `process` using this type class:

```
def process[I](in: I)(implicit p: Processable[I]): p.Out = p(in)
```

Which works as desired (note the appropriate static types):

```
scala> val res: ToUppercaseResponse = process(ToUppercaseRequest("foo"))
res: ToUppercaseResponse = ToUppercaseResponse(FOO)

scala> val res: AddResponse = process(AddRequest(0, 1))
res: AddResponse = AddResponse(1)
```

But it doesn't work on arbitrary types:

```
scala> process("whatever")
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter p: Processable[String]
       process("whatever")
              ^
```

You don't even *have* to use a path dependent type (you should be able just to have two type parameters on the type class), but it makes using `process` a little nicer if e.g. you have to provide the type parameter explicitly.

---

Update: everything above assumes that you don't want to change your case class signatures (which definitely isn't necessary). If you are willing to change them, though, you can do this a little more concisely:

```
trait Input[Out] {
  def computed: Out
}

case class AddRequest(x: Int, y: Int) extends Input[AddResponse] {
  def computed: AddResponse = AddResponse(x + y)
}
case class AddResponse(sum: Int)

case class ToUppercaseRequest(str: String) extends Input[ToUppercaseResponse] {
  def computed: ToUppercaseResponse = ToUppercaseResponse(str.toUpperCase)
}
case class ToUppercaseResponse(upper: String)

def process[O](in: Input[O]): O = in.computed
```

And then:

```
scala> process(AddRequest(0, 1))
res9: AddResponse = AddResponse(1)

scala> process(ToUppercaseRequest("foo"))
res10: ToUppercaseResponse = ToUppercaseResponse(FOO)
```

Which kind of polymorphism (parametric or ad-hoc) you should prefer is entirely up to you. If you want to be able to describe a mapping between arbitrary types, use a type class. If you don't care, or actively don't want this operation to be available for arbitrary types, using subtyping.

Comment: Isn't the second a case of [subtyping polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping) instead of [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Parametric_polymorphism)? Parametric should be the case when a method doesn't depend on the type at all, such as length() on a List[T]?

Comment: @slouc In what sense? The fact that e.g. `right` on `Either[L, R]` returns a `RightProjection[L, R]` is an example of parametric polymorphism, not subtype.

Comment: I mean, `AddRequest` and `ToUppercaseRequest` extend `Input[T]`, method `process` takes an instance of `Input` and is actually being passed subclasses of `Input` (namely, `AddRequest` and `ToUppercaseRequest`). This is subtype, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a common trait for Requests, and a common trait for Responses where the request type is defined for specific response type:

```
trait Request[R <: Response]
trait Response

case class AddRequest(x: Int, y: Int) extends Request[AddResponse]
case class AddResponse(sum: Int) extends Response
case class ToUppercaseRequest(str: String) extends Request[ToUppercaseResponse]
case class ToUppercaseResponse(upper: String) extends Response Response[ToUppercaseRequest]
```

Then, `process` signature would be:

```
def process[A <: Request[B], B <: Response](req: A): B
```

When you call `process`, you'll have to explicitly define the types so that the returned type is what you expect it to be - it can't be inferred specifically enough:

```
val r1: AddResponse = process[AddRequest, AddResponse](AddRequest(2, 3))
val r2: ToUppercaseResponse = process[ToUppercaseRequest, ToUppercaseResponse](ToUppercaseRequest("aaa"))
```

Comment: Hmm. But if I call `process` with an `AddRequest` argument, it will return a `Response[AddRequest]`. I need it to instead return an `AddResponse` from which I can operate on the `sum`.

Comment: Sorry - mixed it up, fixed now: with the explicit typing of the method when it's called, this code runs successfully.

Comment: Hm. Would you mind writing an implementation for `process` as well?

Comment: Hmm, _now_ I see what you're asking - that's where the trick is - how do you _create_ a class of a dynamic type? That's not simple (unless you add a `def getResponse: R` method to `Request` trait and implement it in each request, which would make it trivial).

Comment: Sorry, but the type class pattern means there's no reason you need either a common supertype or explicit type parameters.